# Unexpected Token inside VM, code run flawless

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-chrome

I'm developing one of AJAX and run smoothly and flawless, in short word, **i have no "errors"**.

bit little things disturb me is when i go inspect element it showing this. this is happen when i run my AJAX for second time AND using different trigger.

How i can get rid this message? meanwhile i even dont know where i start with this strange "syntaxerror".

[image]

My Ajax script (using jQuery 1.10.2) :

```html
mobisuiteUserList = {
 urlApiUserList:"",
 urlParam:"",
 currentPage:1,
 limit:10,
 totalPages:1,
 init:function() {
  self = this;
  
  $('#viewUsersButton').click(function() {
   self.currentPage = 1;
   self.viewUser();
  });
  
  $(document.body).on("click","[name=pageButton]",function() {
   self.currentPage = parseInt($(this).attr('data-page-id'));
   self.viewUser();
  });
  
  $(document.body).on("click","#firstButtonList",function() {
   self.currentPage = 1;
   self.viewUser();
  });
  
  $(document.body).on("click","#prevButtonList",function() {
   self.currentPage -= 1;
   self.viewUser();
  });
  
  $(document.body).on("click","#nextButtonList",function() {
   self.currentPage += 1;
   self.viewUser();
  });
  
  $(document.body).on("click","#lastButtonList",function() {
   alert(self.totalPages);
   self.currentPage += self.totalPages;
   self.viewUser();
  });
 },
 
 viewUser:function() {
  self = this;
  
  if(typeof(self.ajax) != "undefined") {
   self.ajax.abort();
  }
  
  //example
  //http://192.168.7.162/user-management/index.php/user/list?data={"order":"asc","limit":2,"dateFrom":"2015-01-23","dateTo":""}
  
  var dateFrom = $('#dateFromSelect').val();
  var dateTo   = $('#dateToSelect').val();
  var startRecord = (self.currentPage - 1) * self.limit;
  
  parameter = "{"+
   '"order":"desc",'+
   '"start":'+'"'+startRecord+'",'+
   '"limit":'+'"'+self.limit+'",'+
   '"dateFrom":'+'"'+dateFrom+'",'+
   '"dateTo":'+'"'+dateTo+'"'+
  "}";
  
  
  self.ajax = $.ajax({
   cache:false,
   url:self.urlApiUserList + "?data="+encodeURIComponent(parameter),
   beforeSend:function() {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    $('#userListTbody').html('<tr><td colspan="6" align="center"><i>Retrieving data...</i></td></tr>');
    $('#pagingUserList').html('');
    $('[name=pageButton]').off();
    $('#firstButtonList').off();
    $('#prevButtonList').off();
    $('#nextButtonList').off();
    $('#lastButtonList').off();
    $('#warningText').hide();
    $('#userLoginLoadingAniGif').show();
   },
   success:function(resp) {
    if(resp.trim().length > 0) {
     var html = "";
     var pagingHtml = "";
     try {
      var parsedData = $.parseJSON(resp);
      var totalViewedUser = parsedData.data.length;
      var totalUser = parsedData.totalRecord;
      
      var remainingRecord = 0;
      
      self.totalPages = Math.floor(totalUser / self.limit);
      remainingRecord = totalUser % self.limit;
      
      if(remainingRecord > 0) {
       self.totalPages += 1;
      }

      pagingHtml = "<ul>";
      
      self.currentPage = parseInt(self.currentPage);
      
      if(self.currentPage == 1) {
       pagingHtml += '<li class="prev disabled"><a href="#">First</a></li>';
       pagingHtml += '<li class="prev disabled"><a href="#">Previous</a></li>';
      } else {
       pagingHtml += '<li class="prev"><a id="firstButtonList" href="#">First</a></li>';
       pagingHtml += '<li class="prev"><a id="prevButtonList" href="#">Previous</a></li>';
      }
      
      //example : PREV - 17 - 18 - 19 - 20
      if(self.currentPage <= 3) {
       var leftBoundaryPageNumber = 1;
      } else {    
       var leftBoundaryPageNumber = self.currentPage - 3;
      }
      
      //example : 20 - 21 - 22 - 23 - NEXT
      if(self.currentPage >=  self.totalPages - 3) {
       var rightBoundaryPageNumber = self.totalPages;
      } else {
       var rightBoundaryPageNumber = self.currentPage + 3;
      }
      
      
      for(pageNumber=leftBoundaryPageNumber;pageNumber < self.currentPage;pageNumber++) {
       if(pageNumber == self.currentPage) {
        pagingHtml += '<li class="active"><a name="pageButton" href="javascript:void()" data-page-id="'+pageNumber+'">'+pageNumber+'</a></li>';
       } else {
        pagingHtml += '<li><a name="pageButton" href="javascript:void()" data-page-id="'+pageNumber+'">'+pageNumber+'</a></li>';
       }
      }
      
      pagingHtml += '<li class="active"><a name="pageButton" href="javascript:void()" data-page-id="'+pageNumber+'">'+pageNumber+'</a></li>';
      for(pageNumber=self.currentPage+1;pageNumber <= rightBoundaryPageNumber;pageNumber++) {
       if(pageNumber == self.currentPage) {
        pagingHtml += '<li class="active"><a name="pageButton" href="javascript:void()" data-page-id="'+pageNumber+'">'+pageNumber+'</a></li>';
       } else {
        pagingHtml += '<li><a name="pageButton" href="javascript:void()" data-page-id="'+pageNumber+'">'+pageNumber+'</a></li>';
       }
      }
      
      if(self.currentPage == self.totalPages) {
       pagingHtml += '<li class="next disabled"><a href="javascript:void()" >Next</a></li>';
       pagingHtml += '<li class="next disabled"><a href="javascript:void()" >Last</a></li>';
      } else {
       pagingHtml += '<li class="next"><a id="nextButtonList" href="javascript:void()" >Next</a></li>';
       pagingHtml += '<li class="next"><a id="lastButtonList" href="javascript:void()" >Last</a></li>';
      }
      
      pagingHtml += "</ul>";
      
      $('#pagingUserList').html(pagingHtml);
      
      for(index=0;index < totalViewedUser;index++) {
       html += "<tr>"+
        "<td>"+ parsedData.data[index].userId +"</td>"+
        "<td>"+ parsedData.data[index].username +"</td>"+
        "<td>"+ parsedData.data[index].firstName + " " + parsedData.data[index].lastName +"</td>"+
        "<td>"+ parsedData.data[index].email +"</td>"+
        "<td>"+ parsedData.data[index].createdDate +"</td>"+
        "<td>"+ "<a href=''>Edit</a> | <a href=''>Delete</a>" + "</td>"+
       "</tr>";
      }
      
      $('#userListTbody').html(html);
     } catch(e) {
      $('#warningText').show();
      $(function () {
       $('#warningText').tooltip({
        title:"Unable to parse retrieved data"
       });
      });
      $('#userListTbody').html('<tr><td colspan="6" align="center"><i>No data to view, please click View button to view data</i></td></tr>');
     }
    } else {
     $('#warningText').show();
     $(function () {
      $('#warningText').tooltip({
       title:"Unable to retrieve user data"
      });
     });
     $('#userListTbody').html('<tr><td colspan="6" align="center"><i>No data to view, please click View button to view data</i></td></tr>');
    }
    $('#userLoginLoadingAniGif').hide();
   },
   error:function() {
    $('#warningText').show();
    $('#warningText').tooltip({
     title:"Unable to retrieve user data"
    });
    $('#userLoginLoadingAniGif').hide();
    $('#userListTbody').html('<tr><td colspan="6" align="center"><i>No data to view, please click View button to view data</i></td></tr>');
   }
  })
 }
}
```

Comment: maybe it´s why you forgot to place a semicolon at the end of your js code line inside `href`? Did you tried that?

Comment: it works now, thanx, i replace href="**javascript:void()**" to href="**javascript:void(0)**"